# Unable to create Twig Global Variable in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, twig-extension

I have already done it using Symfony 3.3 but with Symfony 4 it's not working.

**App\Twig\NotifExt:**

```
    public function getGlobals(){

    $count = 'Hello World';

    return array('count' => $count);        
}
```

**twig_extensions.yaml:**

```
twig:
     globals:
          'count': '%count%'
```

**base.html.twig:**

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">{{ count }} </a>
```

I have done something similar in the previous version and it's working well, but with Symfony 4 I'm getting the following error:

> You have requested a non-existent parameter "count".

Comment: remove single quotes from count variable defined in twig globals.

Comment: @gp_sflover Please add this as an answer so Steve could mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: removed same error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first step is to remove single quotes from `count` variable defined in twig globals.

In your question you seems to define the `count` key using a parameter but to use a service (class) read [How to Inject Variables into all Templates (i.e. global Variables)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html):

```
twig:
    globals:
        yourService: '@App\YourService\Class'
```

and then refers the service method to get the `count` key:

```
{{ yourService.getCount() }}
```

You've many ways to do this but you can play around this simple example to get more ideas.

If the problem it's not resolved you probably need to upgrade your question with more details on how you want to set the `count` key.

PS: have you cleared the cache?

Comment: In getGlobals() I'm counting the no of unread comments and want to make the no global.

Comment: then refers to your service, but remember that your getGlobals() method returns an array. Personally I would prefere to have a specific method like in my answer.

Comment: Now its coming An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").

Comment: As previously said, your getGlobals() method returns an array (_with only one key_), so `return $count` or try `{{ yourService.getGlobals()['count'] }}`

Answer (score 0):

I found something else when checking for similar issue - this might be helpful for somebody.

If you render individual blocks (with `$twig->renderBlock()`) rather than making full render global variables are not automatically merged, so you need to do:

```
        $context = $this->twig->mergeGlobals($parameters);
        $body = $template->renderBlock('body', $context);
```

More info:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8517#issuecomment-21238584