# How to share variables across included templates (or is there an alternative way)?

Tags: symfony, twig, pimcore

For this problem I have a very concrete use case: I am building a library for Pimcore area bricks where the various bricks share certain properties. Like e.g. at least 10 bricks will have the possibility to select a (Twitter Bootstrap) margin between zero and five.

The user of the UI can define a heading type, a margin top and a color for some heading which will be displayed. While the definition of the heading type is *specific* to the heading brick, margin top and color might be used by many other bricks.

So I do a twig template for the margin component

```
{% set marginTopSel = pimcore_select('marginTopSel', {
    store: [1,2,3,4,5],
    reload: true,
    width: 80
}) %}

{% if editmode %}
    <div class="container editprop-container no-material">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <label>{{ "Margin Top"|trans }}</label><br/>
                    {{ marginTopSel | raw }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

And include it in the parent template with:

```
{% include 'marginselectors.html.twig' %}
```

But within the parent template I need the variable `marginTopSel` for the output:

```
{% set marginTop = marginTopSel.getData()|default("") %}
<{{ type }} class="mt-{{ marginTop}}">{{ pimcore_input('headline_text',{'placeholder':'Headline'}) }}</{{ type }}>
```

This is not possible:

> marginTopSel is not defined

There is a way to pass variables *to child templates* in Twig using the `with` keyword: `{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}`. But how can I do it the other way round and get variables defined within an included template into the parent template?

Comment: As far as I can tell you're trying to get variables in "reverse" so to speak. That won't work. But nobody's stoping you from using a twig extension or using a global twig variable with a service as to make it dynamic.

Comment: @Andrei Yes this is what I am trying to do. How would you define such an extension to share variables? "Define an extension" leaves a lot of possibilities for interpretation.

Comment: Well, that's what it's called in twig(or symfony rather). [Twig extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html). Fairly straight forward process. It's basically a service that you can call in twig. If you want persistance across requests, that may be more complicated and could involve a db or something.

Comment: Why not go the other way around and define the variable on the most high template level where you need it, and then pass it through using `with`?

Comment: ^ this. Because of the way you are doing it now, you're making your "main" template too dependent on the `included` ones. What if you need `marginTopSel` before you've included the said child template?

Comment: @NicoHaase Leads to some duplicate code but I might find a solution this way.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicated code"? Defining the variable **once** does not duplicate anything for me

Comment: @NicoHaase in case I would make some master template with all variables yes, but in this use case the top level templates are already automatically included by some other mechanism therefore I can not define something on top of it.

Comment: @NicoHaase Well this is an interesting idea though I might get somewhere with the extends keyword.

Comment: It kinda sounds that what you need are [global variables](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html), but the "reverse variable inheritance" it's kinda confusing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to create Twig Global Variable in Symfony 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123498/unable-to-create-twig-global-variable-in-symfony-4)

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to go about this.

You could either create a..
- Twig extension to get the vars you need. [Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html)
- Service and inject the variable as a global twig variable. [Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html)
- Controller with both the logic and the template and embed the controller instead of including just the template. [Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/embedding_controllers.html)

Comment: link-only answers are discouraged on stackoverflow as links can disappear overtime